# How to create a data grid with Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms, angular-pipe

I am trying to to write a simple data grid layout using Angular 2, grid will just display 10 records at a time and will show a pagination at the bottom (number or record / 10).

(CANNOT USE ANY LIBRARY BECAUSE OF CLIENT RESTRICTION)

Not sure whats the right way to do it, If I could write custom pipe to splice the records dynamically OR ??

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You could try researching, we can't really do your work for ya

Comment: http://4dev.tech/2016/09/creating-an-angular2-datatable-from-scratch/

Comment: ng2-paginate is very good for pagination in angular 2 or 4.